# How to identify unused reports

Tags: soql, dashboard, reports-api, custom-reports

I am trying to perform a task in my org, I need to delete all
unused Reports (those which have not been used in months) from the Org. Can you please suggest if there is a way to Identify "All the reports and dashboards which haven't been used by any user, say in the last 50 days."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

[How to determine old reports and dashboards for deletion?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004237&type=1)

> To locate reports and/or dashboards deemed inactive, create a custom
>   report type with the following:
>
> 1. Navigate to setup > create > report types.  Create a report type with Reports as the primary object and dashboard components as the
>      child object.  Name it "Reports WITH OR WITHOUT Dashboards".
> 2. Create a new report using this new report type.  Include the "Last Run" field.  Run this report.
> 3. Then sort on the dashboard name (Title) column to separate the reports not attached to dashboards.  Finally, observe the last run
>      date of the reports.  If the dashboard's reports do not show a current
>      last run date, then you can assume this dashboard has not been
>      "refreshed".  Refresh triggers the report's "last run".

Comment: Thanks @glls , Can Apex class, triggers, workflows etc change the "Last Run" field of a report?

Comment: TBH, I don't know. You should give it a try :)

Answer (score 3):

Beside @glls answer, and since you added `SOQL` and `API` in your question, you can use `SOQL` to access `Report's LastRunDate` from Apex, you can add WHERE to filter based on your requirements.

[Report object fields you can access.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm)

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastRunDate, LastViewedDate FROM Report
```

[Dashboard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_dashboard.htm) can be accessed also, however it doesnt have LastRunDate.

```
SELECT Id, LastViewedDate FROM Dashboard
```